# 4 students are selected from letters (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I) to go to a show.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

**Question = Bold**

What I know = Regular

(a) **If E, G are going, what's the probability A and C are going?**

-From this, all I know is that there are 7 letters to choose 2 from for those who are going, since it's already given that E and G are going.

(b) **If A is not going, what's the probability B and C are going?**

-There are eight letters that one can choose four from, since A is not going.

(c) **If A, C, D are not going, what's the probability that E, B, F are not going?**

I'm not quite sure on the logic to get the correct answers. Can someone please explain how to do it, because I honestly don't understand how to approach these problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @Arthur thanks, let me edit it.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thanks for informing me, I'll go update what I do know.

Comment: I read the title as "4 students are selected from A-H. Also, I go to a show."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $E$ and $G$ are going, what is the probability $A$ and $C$ are going?

Since $E$ and $G$ are going, two of the other seven students must be selected.  Only one of these selections includes both $A$ and $C$.  Hence, the probability is 
$$\frac{1}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$

> If $A$ is not going, what is the probability $B$ and $C$ are going?

Since $A$ is not going, four students must be selected from the remaining eight students.  If $B$ and $C$ are going, then two students must be selected from the remaining six students.  Hence, the probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{2}}{\dbinom{8}{4}}$$

> If $A$, $C$, and $D$ are not going, what is the probability that $E$, $B$, and $F$ are not going?

If all six students do not go, then at most three students can go to the show. Since four students are going to the show, this is impossible.  Hence, the probability is $0$.

Comment: Is it not true that if you select 4 of 8 and in that 2 of the 8 will appear in the selected four  1/4 of the time

Comment: It is not true.  Since $A$ is not available and $B$ and $C$ are going, we must select two of the remaining six people to go with $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the order does not matter, we know that this is a combination.

Using the combinatorics formula for combinations: nCk= (n choose k)= n!/k! (n-k)!

n is our total number of students, which is 9. k is the chosen number of student, which is 4.

If we plug this in, we get: 9!/ 4! * 5!= 362880/ 2880= 126

Therefore, there are 126 ways to select the students.

If you are still having trouble understanding this, then check out Khan Academy's videos. I only learnt this yesterday, so it's okay if you don't know this yet. It's learning that's important!

Answer (score 0):

Part I, the two other could be chosen in ${7\times6}$ ways. of which A and C are selected in two ways and hence the probability that A and C will go is $\frac{1}{21}$

Part II, If A is not going, there are 8 other people to choose the four and hence ${8\choose4} =70$.  Of which ${6\choose2}$ of them will have B and C and hence the probability that B and C will go is $0.214$

Part III, I do not know how to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

a) The denominator is all the ways in which we can have E and G selected. So if you take the E for example you can put it in any one of 4 places and then the G can go in any one of 3 places. This leaves 2 places which can be filled with any of the remaining letters, i.e. 7*6. Therefore the denominator is 4*3*7*6=504. The numerator is all the ways in which you can arrange A,C,E and G, which is 4*3*2*1=24. The probability is then 24/504 =0.0476.

b) For the denominator we cannot select A, so the number of combinations is 8*7*6*5=1680. For the numerator, it's all the ways we can have B and C (without A) which is 4*3*6*5=360 (B goes in one of 4 places, C in one of 3 places and we select the final 2 places from the 6 remaining possibilities). So it is then 360/1680 = 0.214.

c) The denominator does not include A,C and D so we have all the combinations of the remaining 6. However, in the numerator we are looking for all combinations of these which do not include E,B and F. This leaves only 3 options to choose from, and since we cannot fill 4 places with 3, the probability is 0.

Comment: did not quite understand your Part B, A is not going? is it not

Comment: had a mistake :)